# Team Synchronizing Perspective for Intellij?

Tags: eclipse, svn, intellij-idea, cvs

In eclipse there is a "Team Synchronizing Perspective" that basically does a directory diff to the cvs repository. It is very handy. For various reasons I am looking to move to intellij. Is there an equivalent in intellij with either cvs or svn?

Thanks.

Comment: Intelli J idea svn support really sucks, it doesn't shows me oncoming changes and when I update it just blindly update and ruined my code with backup files. really sucks :-/

Answer (score 15):

Yes. As there's no concept of "perspective" in IDEA, there is the equivalent — a panel called "changes".

IntelliJ IDEA 10 supports CVS, SVN, git and other popular version control systems out of the box. See [the version control feature page](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/version_control.html) on the JetBrains website for more on this.

[image: Changes icon]

Comment: Awesome, thanks! The shelving functionality looks really nice too.

Comment: I can't believe there is nothing similar.  I am having to run a diff on each file, which really sucks.  I don't know, maybe I am overlooking the feature.

Comment: @mattblang I don't understand what kind of feature are you missing? list of changed files?

Comment: @IgorKonoplyanko Somewhere that I can quickly see all of the differences for a group of files (between my local and server VCS).  For example, in Eclipse you can switch to the `Team Synchronize perspective` which will give you a list of all files that have been changed.  Using that list you can quickly switch between the files to see the changes.

Comment: @mattblang check 'Changes' tool window at the bottom of intellij. If it's not there you should configure VCS for your project in settings.
More details you can get from help:
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/changes-tool-window.html

Comment: @IgorKonoplyanko Sure, but if I want to check the differences I have to `Show Diff` on each file.

Comment: @IgorKonoplyanko I see now that you can navigate forward and backward in the `diff window`.  That is definitely better.  Also `Ctrl + d` is a shortcut for showing the diff, which is also better than having to use the mouse.  I do still wish that it was exactly like the `Team Synchronize perspective`.  Not often I will say this, but I did like that feature better in Eclipse.

Comment: @mattblang also in 'Local changes' panel you can click on 'Preview Diff' icon. There will appear small diff window for every selected changed file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48895/discussion-between-mattblang-and-igor-konoplyanko)

Answer (score 2):

for IntelliJ , in the "changes" or "version control", there is a tab that name is "incoming".
you can see the list of you need updating...

sorry, my English is so weak.

Answer (score 0):

Scratch my old answer.  You just need to `right click` whatever folders or files you want to commit and `choose commit from the context menu`, then you will get a `new window` where you can review changes before they are actually committed to the server.

Comment: Yes, but you do not see incoming changes in that dialog like you did in eclipse, or do you?