# Android Studio: How to choose what to import from VCS

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, version-control

I'm using Android Studio 2.1, which is based on IntelliJ IDEA 2016.

If you select `VCS -> Commit changes` there's a nice dialog showing all the modified files and you are able to choose what to commit.

However when selecting `VCS -> Update project` there's no dialog. You have to update everything give or take.

I really miss eclipse's Team Syncronize perspective. It kicked ass compared to this, both for commiting and updating.

Is there a way of displaying a dialog to select which files to update? Or maybe some plugin? I'm getting tired of importing workspace metadata from other team members, or even broken builds when doing bulk updates. The only workaround seems to be looking at the incoming tab first, and then right click over the files you want, which is not very efficient as you have to expand their packages or parent folder first, and you might also need to manually refresh the incoming tab.

Comment: What would be the purpose of ignoring some files' changes when updating?  That would mean you'd end up changing those files back to their old state as part of your next commit.

Comment: @Wyzard The purpose is to avoid downloading bad stuff from the server (which shouldn't be allowed to exist, but often does). My local files don't have to go in the next commit thanks to the wonderful commit dialog were you can select what to upload. I wish this dialog existed for updates too.

Comment: If the files shouldn't be in the repository in the first place, use `.gitignore` to prevent them from being checked in.

Comment: @Wyzard Thats ok, but doesn't work with other VCS like SVN. In SVN you need to go to settings -> blah blah bla -> Ignored files, and even then theres a bunch of project metadata you can't ignore and have to upload for first time but you don't want to update from each dude each time.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution that works for both SVN and Git? Any other source control systems?

Comment: See my answer It seems like Team Synchronizing is missing in intelij @MisterSmith

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that's a nice question but unforunately we have no ways First thing first to checkout documentation of **IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1 Help** given [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/pulling-changes-from-the-upstream-git-pull.html) but not in depth. As vcs-> update will update all files from remote branch and it will never provide you options because it is not implemented yet !!

Also see comments discussion on this answer they have talked about whole issue you have [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4682505/5476209) the question asked little matching with yours is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682412/team-synchronizing-perspective-for-intellij) which is the same having this discussion.

This is unlikely to be an issue with the Android tooling and more likely an issue with the underlying intellij idea software.

This is already discuss over here in google code issues :

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=184086

I have already tried to search plugin or help software but coudn't find one. :(

Comment: If you get a plugin please tell me too @MisterSmith

Answer (score 0):

You just can add a .gitignore file for metadata.

Although, when you update your project it's a good practise to commit files before (and choose only those files you want to update).

Regards!